# Using custom css for iframe in Blogger

Tags: html, css, iframe, blogger

I have some problems using a custom CSS with iframe in Blogger.
I tried to link the CSS in the HTML page to edit the iframe style but nothing worked, I also tried to write the CSS directly in the HTML page but nothing worked.

I want to use a custom CSS for the iframe that I have on my Blogger website.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is you answer:
[How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

> **Edit:** This does not work cross domain.
>
> There are two different things here: the style of the iframe block and
>   the style of the page embedded in the iframe. You can set the style of
>   the iframe block the usual way:
>
> ```html
> <iframe name='iframe1' id="iframe1" src="empty.htm" 
>         frameborder="0" border="0" cellspacing="0"
>         style="border-style: none;width: 100%; height: 120px;"></iframe>
> ```
>
> The style of the page embedded in the iframe must be either set by
>   including it in the child page:
>
> ```htl
> <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="Style/simple.css" />
> ```
>
> Or it can be loaded from the parent page with Javascript:
>
> ```js
> var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
> cssLink.href = "style.css"; 
> cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
> cssLink.type = "text/css"; 
> frames['frame1'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
> ```